# Show ToString of a Collection Wrapper Class in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, overriding, ienumerable

I have a class that has one of its properties being of type `ObservableCollection<string>`

```
public class SizeList
{
    public string ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    //public ObservableCollection<string> List { get; set; }
    public ListEntryCollection List { get; set; }
}
```

During a unit test I return a list of `SizeList` and then show it in a `DataGridView` to check the results I am expecting, the data is fine but I am missing the field `List` in the DGV; only the ID and Name are shown, so I have made a wrapper class for the `ObservableCollection<string>` and overriden its `.ToString()` method:

```
namespace System.Collections.ObjectModel
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public class ListEntryCollection : ObservableCollection<string>
    {
        public ListEntryCollection(IEnumerable<string> collection)
            : base(collection)
        {
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Count.ToString() + ((Count > 1) ? " Entries": " Entry");
        }
    }
}
```

But I am still not getting the `List` field in the DGV, so what am I doing wrong ?

[image: DGV Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [Column Types in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/column-types-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), the only property types for which bound columns are automatically generated are numbers, text, booleans, and images.

To display other types, you need to add the column manually to the `DataGridView`, or use a custom column type (and even then, you'll probably have to add it manually.)

A couple of options present themselves:

- You could try adding a read-only property to `SizeList` to display the description of the list, and see if that will result in a column being automatically created.
- You can try adding a column manually, which I believe you can do in the Form Designer if you click on the `DataGridView`. You will probably have to override a method or two, or use an event handler, in order to change the display from the default. (It's possible, though, that it will use the `ToString` override you created, in which case the problem is solved.)
- Or, you could create a `ListSummaryDataGridViewColumn` class, that can represent a list by display a count of the items in it, and add one of *those* manually.

Comment: You're correct, I tried the enumerable visualizer introduced in VS2022 and it didn't work either. I guess, I will try adding the read-only string property as the DGV is a generic one I made for unit tests, something to simulate the one provided in VS2022. Thanks.